# Parsing JSON image urls to custom Table View error

Tags: ios, json, xcode, parsing

I'm trying to parse a JSON file containing some url's to pictures, titles and texts. I've tried to parse another JSON file in the same way, but only with text and it works. But this one will not work. Here's my code:

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PicturesViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{
    NSURLConnection *conn;
    NSMutableData *responseData;
    NSMutableArray *news;
    NSIndexPath * indexPath;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *loading;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath * indexPath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *tweets;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "PicturesViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RNBlurModalView.h"
#import "PictureJSON.h"

@interface PicturesViewController ()
{
    NSInteger refreshIndex;
    NSArray *images;
}

@end

@implementation PicturesViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showMenu)];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandler:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

     [self issueLoadRequest];
}

- (void)swipeHandler:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [[self sideMenu] showFromPanGesture:sender];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Button actions

- (void)showMenu
{
    [[self sideMenu] show];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source


- (void)issueLoadRequest
{
    // Dispatch this block asynchronosly. The block gets JSON data from the specified URL and performs the proper selector when done.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my-site/pictureparse.php?name=MyName"]];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(receiveData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)receiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // When we have the data, we serialize it into native cocoa objects. (The outermost element from twitter is
    self.tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.tweets.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PictureJSON";

    PictureJSON *cell = (PictureJSON *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PictureJSON" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSDictionary *tweet = [self.tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.instaImage = [tweet objectForKey:@"link"];
    cell.titleLabel.text = [tweet objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.timeLabel.text = [tweet objectForKey:@"published"];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

I have a custom table view file named PictureJSON with a nib file which looks like this:

[image]

But when I launch my app I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<PicturesViewController 0x17d86dc0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key instaImage.'
```

Can someone help me fix this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Just before this line `cell.instaImage = [tweet objectForKey:@"link"];` (that's the one causing the exception), have you checked that `cell` is an instance of `PictureJSON` and not `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure. How do you check that? @neilco

Comment: A simple way would be to add this just before the line I mentioned: `NSLog(@"%@", [cell class]);` This will write the name of cell's type to the console in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the JSON you got not have good structure, check the result of the query in [JSONLint - The JSON Validator](http://jsonlint.com) perhaps this can help you to detect the error.